# parser error - Start tag expected, < not found

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Since we upgraded to php 5.3 we are seeing this error on this app.. Is there anything we can change on the code to make it work again?

---

> Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://servicios1.afip.gov.ar/wsfev1/service.asmx?WSDL' : Start tag
>   expected, '<' not found in
>   /home/whlatam/public_html/e-factura/inc/funciones.php on line 373

---

On line 373 of file funciones.php we have this

```
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at,

```
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost/webservice/Expression?wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found\n in /usr/share/php/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 760
```

It seems that you haven't enable OpenSSL.

Since you are loading the WSDL from https, you should enable OpenSSL.

Run the following command on the terminal (where you have hosted your app) to check whether it is enabled,

```
echo '<?php phpinfo(); ?>' | php 2>&1 |grep -i ssl
```

You should get output like below, if OpenSSL is enabled.

```
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL support => enabled
```

If not, enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering late. If you are using nusoap then you should be calling function **nusoap_client().**