# Start tag expected, '<' not found soap error

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm new to webservice in php

I have two pages like

service.php where the code is

```
<?php
//call library
require_once ('lib/nusoap.php');

//using soap_server to create server object
$server = new soap_server;


//register a function that works on server 
$server->register('get_message'); 

// create the function 
function get_message($your_name) 
{ 
if(!$your_name){ 
return new soap_fault('Client','','Put Your Name!'); 
} 
$result = "Welcome to ".$your_name .". Thanks for Your First Web Service Using PHP with SOAP"; 
return $result; 
} 
// create HTTP listener 
if ( !isset( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) ) $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA =file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
exit(); 

?>
```

and another page is like client.php

```
    <?php
    require_once ('lib/nusoap.php');

    $client = new soapclient('http://localhost/webservice/nusoap/service.php',array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2));
    //Give it value at parameter 
    $param = array( 'your_name' => 'Jayatna ROY'); 
    //Create object that referer a web services 

    //Call a function at server and send parameters too 
    $response = $client->call('get_message',$param); 
    //Process result 
    if($client->fault) 
    { 
    echo "FAULT: <p>Code: ".$client->faultcode."</p>"; 
    echo "String: ".$client->faultstring; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    echo $response; 
    } 
    ?>
```

and I am geeting an error like this 
 Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost/webservice/nusoap/service.php' : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\wamp\www\webservice\nusoap\client.php on line 4

will you please solve my eorror 
Thanks in advance

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538343/magento-api-soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from-url-index-php-api-in

Comment: I have made all the respective changes to fix it as for example openssl,curl in php.ini file but no result so far

Comment: why don't u try to use build in server http://php.net/manual/en/soapserver.construct.php

Comment: You can find the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836128/parser-error-start-tag-expected-not-found/35061044#35061044